# Print significant auto-correlation values in R

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

If I do an autocorrelation test in R (using function `acf`), I get a great graph, and the horizontal lines show the cutoff of significance.

Function `acf` also prints out the individual lag values in the console, however, here I can't see which are significant. Is there an easy way to do that without looking at the graph?

Comment: Is your question about determining significant lag values or plotting the cutoff?  Please note that questions that are only about doing something in software are off-topic here.

Comment: In that case I should repost to stackoverflow, as I just want to know how to basically put a star or so next to the significant value.

Comment: I have reposted it and will delete this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248624/print-significant-auto-correlation-value-in-r

Comment: You should not delete and repost. As the [help/on-topic] explains, you should instead flag it for migration. (You'll know for next time)

Comment: This could have been a statistical question if you asked how to obtain the standard error of an ACF estimate (which you could use for determining statistical significance).

Comment: @dorien: so you could delete it now